# python3 reading large file exhausts memory

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to read a large file of line based text in Python 3 (both 3.6 and 3.8) on Ubuntu 18.04.4, but doing so exhausts the memory because the buff/cache usage climbs to consume all available (physical) memory.

I've searched ***a lot*** for answers and the standard solution offered in many, many posts is to read line by line. However, this behavior occurs even when reading line by line - as in the (simplified exemplar) code below.

```
with open(file, 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        pass
```

I've also searched how to limit the use/size of the buff/cache, but could not find anything. Constantly clearing the cache (eg, with `sudo echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`) is not a viable option.

The file size is ~20GB and physical RAM is 16GB, starting with ~12GB free when I run the code.

How can I *actually* read a large file without exhausting memory?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you need to configure additional swap space so that process virtual memory can be spilled to disk to make room in physical memory for the rest of the file.  See 'man mkswap' and 'man swapon' for starting points. Ask in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) if you need assistance with that.

Comment: Also, the "read a line at a time" approach only works if you're able to read and process a line, or a reasonable number of lines, and then discard those lines and reuse their space (i.e. reuse the variables that hold the lines) for the next batch of lines.  If you read lines in and simply accumulate all of them until you reach end-of-file then the final memory footprint is no different than reading the entire file in one go.  In fact it might be worse.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, ottomeister. On the first one, I (coincidentally) already did configure more swap and that had not affect. However, I don't understand what effect more swap has on the buff/cache use, especially since swap is not being hit at all (by design).

Comment: On the second comment, even when I run the read loop in my original post - which does nothing with the data read, just throws it away by moving on to the next line - the buff/cache utilization still increases until all memory is exhausted. I would prefer not to throw away each line, but I can refactor to do so, if only i could get the read loop to work as "advertised".

Comment: There is some underlying problem that I'm missing....